# Find substring in array

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to count the count the number occurences of a substring in a field in an array.

Example:
The XML below has 3 occurences of the substring 'TXT1' in Field1.

```
  <Level1>
    <Level2>
      <Field1>10000TXT1</Field1>
      <Field1>TXT210000</Field1>
      <Field1>10001TXT1</Field1>
      <Field1>TXT30000</Field1>
      <Field1>10TXT1000</Field1>
      <Field1>TXT20000</Field1>
    </Level2>

fun countOccurences(txtToSearchFor) =
  // Some code that can count how many times the text 'TXT1' occur in all the Field1 fields.
```

I have tried the examples below, but they dont work

1)

```
trim(upper(Field1)) contains "TXT1"
```

2)

```
(((Field1) find 'TXT1') joinBy '')
```

Hope you can help :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use the function [sumBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-arrays-functions-sumby) from the [dw::core::Arrays](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-arrays-functions-sumby) module. This function takes an array and a lambda that returns the number to be `added` for each element in the array. So then I just need to ask for the times of repetitions of a String inside another String. That is achieved by using [sizeOf](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-sizeof) and [find](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-find#find3)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import sumBy from dw::core::Arrays

fun timesOf(value: Array<String>, txtToSearchFor: String) =
    value sumBy ((text) ->  sizeOf(text find  txtToSearchFor))
---
payload.Level1.Level2.*Field1 timesOf "TXT1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: :-)

```
fun countOccurences(texts) = 
    sizeOf (Level1.Level2.*Field1 filter ($ contains texts))
```